# Using IGMP but Multicast still Flooding

Tags: switching, multicast, igmp, aruba

Im new here.

I want to ask about the multicast,

The first case is, I have switch HP 2530 24 port with 24 10/100 and 2 100/1000 NIC, And i have servers with bandwidth video multicast around 120-125Mbps. Servers plug into 2 gigabit NIC switch and the client into 10/100 NIC. Using IGMPv2 as the default.

The problem is,

1. When I set IGMP to mode AUTO the video is good and multicast not flooding to the client. But after 5-10 minutes the client stop receive multicast traffic.
2. And I set IGMP to mode FORWARD, Client receive multicast trafiic and video NOT stopping after 5-10 minutes. But the problem is the client only have 10/100 NIC but multicast traffic send bandwidth around 120mbps, so when i start playing video, The video is Lagging.

Any suggestion guys? maybe have a sollution for this problem?

Thanks.

This is my igmp config

```
     IGMP Service Protocol Info

  Total VLANs with IGMP enabled                : 1
  Current count of multicast groups joined     : 1

  IGMP Filter Unknown Multicast: Enabled
  IGMP Filter Unknown Multicast Status: Enabled

  VLAN ID : 1
  VLAN Name : DEFAULT_VLAN
  IGMP version : 2
  IGMP is not enabled

  VLAN ID : 100
  VLAN Name : iptv
  IGMP version : 2
  Querier Address : Querier initial wait

  Active Group Addresses Type       Expires         Ports      Reports Queries
  ---------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ------- -------
  239.255.255.250        Filter     0h 3m 30s       13-16      646     0


 VLAN ID : 100
  VLAN NAME : iptv
  IGMP Enabled [No] : Yes
  Querier Allowed [Yes] : Yes

  Port    Type       | Port Mode Forced Fast Leave Fast Leave
  ------- ---------- + --------- ----------------- ----------
  13      10/100TX   | Auto      No                Yes
  14      10/100TX   | Auto      No                Yes
  15      10/100TX   | Auto      No                Yes
  16      10/100TX   | Auto      No                Yes
  17      10/100TX   | Auto      No                Yes
  18      10/100TX   | Auto      No                Yes
  19      10/100TX   | Auto      No                Yes
  20      10/100TX   | Auto      No                Yes
  21      10/100TX   | Blocked   No                Yes
  22      10/100TX   | Auto      No                Yes
  23      10/100TX   | Forward   Yes               Yes
  24      10/100TX   | Auto      No                Yes
  25      1000T      | Auto      No                Yes
  26      1000T      | Auto      No                Yes
```

Comment: Did you configure the switch as a multicast querier?

Comment: i already edit my Q, probably you must to see my config, is that wrong ?

Comment: Please, never ever use images for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into your question using the Preformatted-text feature (`{}`).

Comment: sorry, im new contributor. thats my fault :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the 2530 for IGMP forwarding, otherwise it'll simply flood.

For instance,

```
vlan 1 ip igmp
```

turns on IGMP forwarding for VLAN 1 and sets the switch querier to automatic mode.

Additionally, you can use the `vlan x ip igmp` options to disable all but one switch as querier - there must be one querier for each cast - and to limit IGMP casts to specific addresses.

**EDIT**: what you call *config* is a `show ip igmp` output. It does however give several hints.

```
Querier Address : Querier initial wait
```

indicates a problem with the querier - no querier, no multicast. For the switch to work as querier it requires an IP address for the VLAN.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers, sir.
I will try ur instructions.